# Mos score calculation of opus codec with E-Model algorithm

Tags: opus

Now we want to use E-model algorithm to calculate opus Mos score, we need to feed some parameters to E-model, e.g. bpl, ie, currently I can't find the value of these params for opus in web, anyone can help? Or do you know any other widely used algorithm for opus mos?

Comment: Hi, did you find the params?

Answer (score 0):

[ITU-T E-model tutorial.](https://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com12/emodelv1/tut.htm)
Look at the table 2 there are default values for each parameters and recommended range.